# Updating form field base on selected item from drop down (jquery, PHP & MySQL)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a database table that holds booking extras in the format:

```
name:price
```

I get a PHP array of the booking extras from the database and create a select box containing their names and also display a price field:

```
<label class="label">Name</label>
<label class="select">
  <select id="name" name="name">
  <?php 
foreach ($upsells as &$upsell) {
  echo '<option value="'.$upsell['name'].'">'.$upsell['name'].'</option>';
}
  ?>
  </select>
</label>
<label id="pricet" class="label" style="display:none;">Price</label>
<label class="input" id="price" style="">
  <input class="" id="price" type="text" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?" name="price" value="" >
</label>
```

I am trying to get the price box to auto update with the correct price associated with the item name when it is selected from the select box.

Using jquery, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name").change(function () {
    var choice = jQuery(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url:'/get_upsell.php?pid=<?php echo $urlcrypt->encrypt($pid);?>',
      type:'GET',
      data : {'id' : choice},
      success : function(response) {
      $('input[name="name"]').val(response.name);
      $('input[name="price"]').val(response.price);
      }
    });
  });
})
```

And get_upsell.php

```
if (isset($_GET['pid'])){
  $pid = $urlcrypt->decrypt($_GET['pid']);
}

$jsonupsells = $users->get_upsells_ajax($pid);

$indexedOnly = $jsonupsells;

foreach ($associative as $row) {
  $indexedOnly[] = array_values($row);
}

return json_encode($indexedOnly);
```

The json string is created when I call get_upsells.php (I checked manually) but I cant see any ajax request coming from the browser when selecting an item.

Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT: Found a missing , after the 'GET'. I am now seeing the ajax requests but cant work out how to update the "price" form field.

EDIT: JS function now looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name").change(function () {
    var choice = jQuery(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url:'/get_upsell.php?pid=<?php echo $urlcrypt->encrypt($pid);?>',
      type:'GET',
      data : {'id' : choice},
      success : function(response) {
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        $('input[name=price]').val(response.price);
      }
    });
  });
})
```

And changed database query so it only returns the values for the selected item based on item id. Also changed "return" to "echo".

Still no updating of the price field.

UPDATE:

changed the function to:

```
$('#price').val('Hello');
```

And that populates the price field with 'Hello' so it looks like the...

```
response.price
```

...bit is not passing the data.

Comment: can you see the ajax response on firebug or developer tools or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error after `type:'GET'`

EDIT: You need to parse to JSON object.

```
success : function(response) {
response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

After this to set value you need to remove quotes.

```
$('input[name=acct]').val(response.price);
```

EDIT 2: For ajax You must `echo` JSON, not `return` (in php file)

Answer (score 0):

Now fixed with:

```
$('#price').val(response[0].price);
```